# Get error message from a custom redirect error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    if (UserHasPermission())
    {
        return View()
    }

    throw new HttpException(403, "You do not have permission");
}
```

and in my web.config I set this:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error/403" />
</customErrors>
```

I want to know how to get this message 'You do not have permission' when the redirect to Error/403 is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just the redirects to a given url and sends it the Url that caused the error. It does not, however, store any information, it's simply a url redirection.

More details here: [Custom Error Page - Throw HttpException and have custom error page show message](http://forums.asp.net/t/1822665.aspx/1)